# Can I re-map a CRM 2011 System user after importing the database?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have imported a CRM 2011 database from an outside domain and mapped one admin user to my local account on my local domain and left all other users unmapped.

Can I remap any of the other users or am I stuck reimporting the database and mapping properly? I want to map one of the other users to a different account on my new domain because I want to login as this user (not the user I originally mapped).

Comment: By mapping do you mean populating the Domain name?

Comment: I really wanted the "map users" editor as it is given when you import an org with the deployment manager... but it sounds like changing the domain name will do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can perform the mapping process again (as its presented in the organisation import tool) but you can just change the domain/login name on the system user record. This should achieve the same result, if you need to update 100's of records you might be able to update the records with a data import, or failing that write a little application to do it.

Comment: I am getting a seperate error related to my new domain when I attempt that, but it should be resolvable. I didnt want to bother looking into it without knowing that should "just work". Thanks.